# How to getrid of Search.sidecubes

Tags: firefox, mozilla, malware, virus

Malware Search.sidecubes has affected by mozilla firefox

Using google, I uninstalled all programs which could be related to searchcubes, further I deleted all add-on's and also checked regedit, about:config, checked folders in ../users/appdata/local/mozilla etc etc. I managed to get rid of search.sidecubes getting set as homepage.

But now even after selecting google as default search option (including about:config page), whenever I search anything in search toolbar of firefox it always redirects to search.sidecubes instead of Google.

same issue is also happening in google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is well suited for SO. Anyway, Mozilla SUMO has a nice support guide about how to deal with [malware on Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/sr/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-caused-malware).

Some suggestions extracted from that page:

1. If you're executing Firefox from a link, make sure the link does not contain any undesired command line option.
2. Use the [SearchReset](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchreset/) addon to clean up your default page and reset settings.
3. Scan using Malwarebytes Anti-malware free.